# Access header's properties within a $http call in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, http-headers, request-headers

Following github API's documentation for pagination, I'm trying to request event items and retrieve the `Link` header ([just like they suggest](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination)) to build the pagination. The problem is that I don't know how to handle the `headers('Link')` object.

**Function:**

```
getEvents: function(page) {        
        if(cacheService.get('eventos_'+page)) {
          return cacheService.get('eventos_'+page);
        } else {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          $http.get('https://api.github.com/repos/'+owner+'/'+repo+'/events', {params: {per_page: 15, page: page}})
          .success(function(events, status, headers) {
            console.log(events, status, headers('Link'));
               cacheService.put('eventos_'+page, events);
            deferred.resolve(events);
          }).error(function(err) {
            deferred.reject('Error', err);
          });
          return deferred.promise;
        }
      }
```

The resulting "object" (if it can be called like that) is:

```
"
<https://api.github.com/repositories/XXXXXX/events?page=2&per_page=15>; rel="next",
<https://api.github.com/repositories/XXXXXX/events?page=4&per_page=15>; rel="last"
"
```

¿How can save page (next and last) numbers in $scope variables? or at least how can I traverse that object?
Don't laugh, but I tried `headers('Link').rel['last']` without success, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the angular $http document https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
The response object has these properties:

```
data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.
```

And to get data from headers its headers['Link'] if you can see 'Link' in your response header

Below is the code to get pagination links from header if you are sending pagination parameters in response header

```
function parseHeader(header){
 // Split parts by comma
        var parts = header.split(',');
        var links = {};
        // Parse each part into a named link
        angular.forEach(parts, function (p) {
            var section = p.split(';');
            if (section.length != 2) {
                throw new Error("section could not be split on ';'");
            }
            var url = section[0].replace(/<(.*)>/, '$1').trim();
            var queryString = {};
            url.replace(
                new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"),
                function($0, $1, $2, $3) { queryString[$1] = $3; }
            );
            var page = queryString['page'];
            if( angular.isString(page) ) {
                page = parseInt(page);
            }
            var name = section[1].replace(/rel="(.*)"/, '$1').trim();
            links[name] = page;
        });

        return links;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any other method, or best practice to do that? Instead of splitting and "manually traversing" the object... I don't know, it doesn't feel to be the correct way, although it may work.

Comment: By the way, the object is not always the same, sometimes it comes with "2 parts" (like the one in your example) but sometimes it comes with 4 parts, including, first page, previous page, next page and last page... Your code won't work this time